# why is my htaccess adding current page url to all links on the page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am new to htaccess rewrite rules but with some few tutorials i've been able to write some few rules but the problem now is that the rules work well but every links on the page is preceded with the current page link therefore rendering all links on the page invalid. Below is a sample code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^school/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ school.php?country=$1&school=$2 [NC,L]
```

For example if i access school page as school/spain/university the link to my index page which is supposed to be index would change to school/spain/universty/index

I've searched everywhere for a similar problem or solution  but i didn't see any.

Comment: This happens, when you have relative links instead of absolute links, e.g. `index` vs `/index`. And this is nothing, which can be fixed with .htaccess, but only by creating proper HTML.

Comment: It tried using and absolute path and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the problem is to use base link at the head of your page.

This solves the problem perfectly, it doesn't matter if you're using relative link or absolute link.